# sscanf skipping the final value when reading multiple values from a line

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to take input from a file, the file is formatted and has 5 values per line, the code only read the first 4 and skip to the next line.

The file is formatted as follow:

```
1 | 1 | 1 | qwqqqqqqqq | q |
2 | 2 | 2 | a | a |
3 | 3 | 3 | e | e |
(this line has nothing)
```

```
 char buffer[100];
 for(int i=0; i<numofline; i++)
    {
        fgets(buffer,100,fr);

        sscanf(buffer,"%d | %d | %d | %[^|]s | %[^|]s |\n", &dump, &sa[i].v1, &sa[i].v2,sa[i].v3, sa[i].v4);

        printf("%-5d%-5d%-5d%-20s%-20s\n", dump, sa[i].v1, sa[i].v2,sa[i].v3,sa[i].v4);
     }
```

I expect the result to be just like the file, which is

```
1    1    1    qwqqqqqqqq  q
2    2    2    a           a
3    3    3    e           e
```

but the actual result is missing the final column

```
1    1    1    qwqqqqqqqq
2    2    2    a         
3    3    3    e
```

Comment: Also note the behaviour of [trailing white space in a `scanf()` format string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499060/what-is-difference-between-scanfd-and-scanfd).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Fortunately that's less important if you're reading from a string.

Comment: catmandx, Who or what text suggested an 's' in `"%[^|]s"`?

Answer (score 5):

`%[^|]s` always fails because `%[^|]` consumes all non-pipe characters including `s`, so `s` then never matches.

That is, `%[^|]` is a scanf input directive, but `s` in the format string just matches itself. Just remove that `s`.

Also, always check the return value of `scanf` to see how many variables were successfully filled.

```
if (sscanf(buffer, "%d | %d | %d | %[^|] | %[^|] |",
                   &dump, &sa[i].v1, &sa[i].v2, sa[i].v3, sa[i].v4) != 5) {
    /* handle input error somehow */
}
```

Comment: why did the first %[^|]s work? It successfully returned the correct string to the correct variable (sa[i].v3)

Comment: @catmandx the `%[]` succeeds, but the literal `s` - and thus everything after it - fails

Comment: ah, okay, one more thing, I can't put the width specifier in without breaking the result, i want the v3 and v4 values to have maximum of 20 characters, is this right? %d | %d | %d | %[20][^|] | %[20][^|] |\n

Comment: @catmandx: You can use `%20[^|]` to read up to 20  bytes into a string of not less than 21 bytes.  Beware the off-by-one.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I did that and I made v3 in the file 20 characters long, the code returns a v3 = v3(in file) + v4(in file) which makes it 20 + len (v4) long. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Use longer string variables?  Or a shorter length in the format string.

Comment: I'm struggling with it, do you have any ideas what caused it? What do you mean by longer string?